# Rails List record and count for each

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a model called Note.  Each note belongs_to :call_reason.  And call_reason has_many :notes.

What I want to do in a view is display a list of call_reasons and a total count of each next to it so we can see what the most popular call reasons are.

Here's what I have so far:

dashboard_controller:

```
  def index
    @notes = Note.all
  end
```

dashboard view:

```
<% @notes.each do |n| %>
   <%= n.call_reason.reason %>
<% end %>
```

This lists all notes' call_reasons.

I'm stumbling on how to list each call_reason once with a total count next to it.  What I have now just lists all the call_reasons per note which is a mess.  I think I could scope this out somehow or change the instance variable but I'm having a hard time getting it right.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think this might be a candidate for activerecord group_by but I need to figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to list call reasons, you should start with that:

```
def index
  @call_reasons = CallReason.all
end
```

Then in your view you can do this:

```
<% @call_reasons.each do |call_reason| %>
  <%= call_reason.reason %> <%= call_reason.notes.count %>
<% end %>
```

Note that this will perform a query for every call reason in your database. To prevent this you can use a [counter cache](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column). Check out the section on [counter cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-counter_cache) on Rails Guides too.

Comment: This works great but generates a lot of queries on the backend.  Is there a way to refactor this using group_by?  Would that lessen the queries?

Comment: I recommend using a counter cache to solve that problem. I added a more up-to-date link on the subject. Good luck.